# pandas - project bipartite network from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a dataframe representing a weighted bipartite network like the following:

```
L1,L2,w
1,A,0.9
2,A,0.2
3,A,0.5
1,B,0.9
2,B,0.8
```

where nodes in the L1 column are connected to nodes in the L2 column with a weight value associate to each edge (w).

[image: Bipartite Network]

I would like to project the network into the L1 level. The first step is connecting L1 values if they are connected to the same L2 values, multiplying the weights, such as:

```
1,2,0.9*0.2
2,3,0.2*0.5
1,3,0.9*0.5
1,2,0.9*0.8
```

The second step is building a new dataframe (weighted edge list) summing up the weights of the duplicate edges:

```
1,2,0.9*0.2 + 0.9*0.8
2,3,0.2*0.5
1,3,0.9*0.5
```

I know that it's a bit weird; I tried the same approach using the networkx bipartite function, but it's a little bit tricky working on weights within it, so I would prefer working with pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2 = df.merge(df,on='L2')

df3 = df2[ df2.L1_x > df2.L1_y ]              # drop duplicates and matches to self

df3['w'] = df3.w_x * df3.w_y                  # multiply weights

df4 = df3.groupby(['L1_y','L1_x'])['w'].sum()

L1_y  L1_x
1     2       0.90
      3       0.45
2     3       0.10
```